# Reset Css values Onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am very new to Jquery,so don't take me in a wrong way.
I have some images and when the user clicks on the images its opacity should be reduced .and when the user clicks on the other image it should regain its original property.

The regex replacements and applying glass id to it are additional changes.
How do i reset the css value when the user clicks on other image.

Here is  my Jquery code.

```
$("#list img").click(function () {

$(this).css("opacity",".3");
var selectImgName =  $(this).attr("src");

selectImgName = selectImgName.replace("c", "b");

$("#glasses").attr("src", selectImgName);
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div id="list"   >
<img src="img/c1.png" style="display:box; width:125px; margin-left:5px; margin-top:9px" />
<img src="img/c2.png" style="display:box; width:125px;margin-left:5px;margin-top:9px"/>
<img src="img/c3.png" style="display:box; width:125px;margin-left:5px;margin-top:9px" />    
<img src="img/c4.png" style="display:box; width:125px;margin-left:5px;margin-top:9px"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("#list img").css("opacity","1"); //reset all
$(this).css("opacity",".3"); //set on clicked
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6XNU/)

Comment: How can i make the 1st image property as clicked image(opacity=.3) on default and then change accordingly.

Comment: So you click on the image and it becomes more opaque? Just set the CSS style to .3 which sets it as default and then swap the values in the code above.

Comment: can you help with jsfiddle

Comment: No, i want the 1st image to be with opacity .3 on default,and should change to 1 when the user clicks on other image.and the clicked image to turn to .3 when clicked .

Comment: i have another image for heading ,which is being affected with this child. http://jsfiddle.net/viru48/8RAQJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just restore the original opacity of all images and then change the one that was clicked.

```
$("#list img").click(function () {
    $("#list img").css("opacity", "1");
    $(this).css("opacity",".3");
});
```

This should work.

Comment: How can i make the opacity of 1st (img/c1.png) image as a clicked image(opacity =.3)as default and then apply the above code.